# How to export data from multiple tables in a dynamic fashion in plsql

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I have an plsql SP that creates multiple tables on a daily basis, however the number of tables are not always the same, however, the generated tables have a predefined pattern in its name.

I'm trying to create a plsql SP who exports those tables to a csv or excel file, based on a list input with the name of the generated tables.

Any ideas for achieving this rather than use PLSQL or is there any useful way of achieve this with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this question is very abstract and can have many solutions. Here is a solution that you can try if you want to create Excel from your data.

First you need a tool to create an excel file. Anton Scheffer has developed a package that you can use to create easily an Excel file from a cursor. Have a look: [Create an Excel-file with PL/SQL](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/).

Next, you can determine the created tables and  create a query string that you can pass as parameter into `query2sheet` procedure of the Anton's package. All Tables you can find in `user_tables` View.

So your code could looks like:

```
for rec in (select * from user_tables where 1=1 /* or condition you need to filter the correct tables*/)
loop

  -- as_xlsx -  is a package created by Anton Scheffer
  as_xlsx.query2sheet( 'select * from '||rec.table_name );

  -- MY_DIR is a database Directory that you have to create
  as_xlsx.save( 'MY_DIR', rec.table_name||'.xlsx' );


end loop;
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to create a csv files, so you can use a package developed by William Robertson, [Ref cursor to CSV converter](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml).
The usage is quite similar to the Excel package.